# referencing css in html as part of angular application

Tags: html, css, angular

I am creating an anuglar 2 app with asp.net webapi 2 to fetch data. I am using html pages and not the Asp.net cshtml page to render the screen. I have two css files that is Bootstrap.css and Site.css in my application project. I have both the css files that are configured to be bundled in bundle.config file. Please see the code below

```
   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
```

The MVC layout has the following code which takes care of implementing the CSS files in MVC

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

This however does not take care of the html pages that I have built for angular. Hence I have made an explicit reference to it in the index.html page like seen below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


    <base href="/">

    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/primeui/themes/omega/theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css" />

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">-->
    <!--<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>-->
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-app></my-app>


</body>
</html>
```

I just want to verify if my implementation is right.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the native `.cshtml` page, don't use the native bundling feature either. If your project is quite new, just move on to [Angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/) that will handle the bundling for you.

Otherwise, do it with gulp (or your loved task runner).